# Ubuntu Wifi portal login privacy

Tags: hotspot, ubuntu-18.04

Is there a way to enact 'privacy mode' for the browser used to log in to WiFi portals, like at Starbucks, etc.?  Specifically, interested in avoiding them depositing a cookie.

Perhaps it's possible to change the default browser used?

Using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

The *portal helper* component of GNOME Shell uses an embedded WebKitGTK web view.

Starting with GNOME Shell 3.24, the portal-helper always creates an ["ephemeral" web view](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=780453), which doesn't store any data to disk. In other words, it is always in "privacy mode".

Comment: This suggests the 'auto login' type of features cookies bring no longer function